# NGINX Reverse Proxy for 2 jenkins servers. How?

Tags: nginx, jenkins, reverse-proxy

I would like to run 2 jenkins server behind nginx reverse proxy, but I can not find the proper to configure it.

The config below is working fine

```
location /jenkins {
          proxy_pass https://contoso.com/jenkins;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

If i try to change location to `/jenkins_test`, than it does not work anymore.

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You will need two define each jenkins instance in its own server section. 
Then depending on the url that you are calling on nginx, the right jenkins server will respond. 
Your nginx config could have a structure like this:

```
http{

    # application server for first jenkins instance
    upstream app_servers_first_jenkins_instance {

    # if jenkins is running on the same server this should be something like 127.0.0.1 ...
        server https://contoso.com/jenkins;

    }

    # application server for secons jenkins instance
    upstream app_servers_second_jenkins_instance {

        server https://contoso.com/jenkins;

    }

# JENKINS SERVER 1 
server{
listen 80;
  server_name jenkinsfirstinstance.yourdomain.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://app_servers_first_jenkins_instance;
   }
}

# JENKINS SERVER 2
server{

listen 80;
  server_name jenkinssecondinstance.yourdomain.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://app_servers_second_jenkins_instance;
   }
}   

} # END OF HTTP SECTION
```

In this example both urls will call the same jenknins endpoint (https://contoso.com/jenkins) if you want them to be different jenkins instances you will have modify this url in one of the upstream sections

Comment: Unfortunately, I can use only links like http://contoso.com/jenkins1 and http://contoso.com/jenkins2

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run 2 servers behind the nginx proxy, that's mean you need 2 location contexts (also called "blocks").

In your configuration file which is probably located in `/etc/nginx/sites-availables` you should add the locations:

```
http{
    listen 80;

    location /jenkins1 {
      proxy_pass http://jenkins1-local-ip-address:8000;
      include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }
    location /jenkins2 {
      proxy_pass http://jenkins2-local-ip-address:8001;
      include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }
}
```

One thing you schould note is that I consider that your jenkins server is in same LAN (Local Area Network) otherwise it will not make sense to habe a proxy in front because your sever is already accessible via internet.

If your jenkins servers are accessible via HTTPS you schould change `http` to `https` in a location context and edit the port number to `listen 443` and some ssl certificates configurations.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to avoid using different ports instead of different links? Like https://contoso.com/jenkins1 and https://contoso.com/jenkins2 ?

Comment: Yes it is possible.  But in that case your servers should run on 2 different physical machines. Note that the address passed as parameter to the proxy_pass directive can be specified as a domain name or IP address, and an optional port" reference http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass

But it recommend to set the IP address if the servers is in your LAN to avoid sending requests to your DNS-Server.

Comment: For me to provide more details I need the topology of your network. On which machine which server is running? Do yo have every servers (jenkins and nginx) on a same server?